# How can I merge 2 carts into 1 in Instacart? The 2 carts are from the same store

Tags: untagged

How can I merge 2 carts into 1 on the [Instacart website](https://www.instacart.com/store)? The 2 carts are from the same store.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to merge 2 carts into 1 on the Instacart website.